# How many ordered pairs of real numbers (a, b) satisfy equality?

Tags: integration

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^{2}x}{e^{ax}-2bx-1}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

I think it's zero .... I used L'hopital I took the derivative above and below to not get a 0/0 limit. AE was $\frac {0} {(ae ^ {ax}) - 2b}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{e^{ax}-2bx-1}&=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}{ae^{ax}-2b}& \textrm{(L'H)} \\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{2\cos2x}{a^2e^{ax}} &\textrm{(L'H)} \\
&=\frac{2}{a^2}
\end{align}

<s>Since the value of the limit is independent of $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{b}$, and $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{a-2}$ satisfies the limit, there are infinitely many pairs of ordered pairs$\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{(a,b)}$.  The general solution is $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{(a,b)=(2,b),\ b\in\mathbb{R}.}$</s>

EDIT:  In order to apply L'H in the second step of the calculations, the denominator $ae^{ax}-2b$ has to be equal to $0$ when $x=0$.  Solving:
\begin{align}
ae^{ax}-2b&=0\\
ae^0-2b&=0\\
a-2b&=0\\
a&=2b
\end{align}

Once we have this, recognize that $a=\pm2$ satisfies the limit, and as such, $b=\pm1$.  Therefore, the only real ordered pairs $(a,b$) are $(2,1)$ or $(-2,-1)$.

Comment: Small correction. The general solution should be $(a, b) = (\pm 2, b), b \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: The condition $a=2b$ needs to hold, otherwise you cannot use L'H in step 2. The only solution acceptable would be $(2,1)$ and $(-2, -1)$.

Comment: Yes, I recognized this right after, writing an edit atm.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of EuxHenH, we use l'Hopital on $\frac{2\sin{x}\cos{x}}{ae^{ax}-2b}$ to get $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {\frac{2(\cos^2{x} - \sin^2{x})}{a^2e^{ax}-2b}} = \lim _{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{2\cos{(2x)}}{a^2e^{2bx}}} = \frac{2}{a^2}$$

Thus the solution set is $(a, b) = (\pm 2, b) \ \forall \ b \in \mathbb{R}$.